# htaccess tagging system custom htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having trouble understanding the .htaccess file and the formatting; basically my question is how would I accomplish a link like this; /tag/hashtag/category

so I would have one index file in the tag directory which would grab the hashtag and category? and regardless of the input of the hash-tag and the category it would still take me to the index file in the tag directory.

Sorry for the real basic question/request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the content of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /tag/index.php?hash=$1&cat=$2
```

`([^/]+)` means that we want to capture a string witch contains characters that are not `/`, so we get all characters between two slashes.